# Не открывать браузер после создания экземпляра WebBrowser

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Использую код с: [Код для получения скриншота веб-страницы по ссылке(GitHub)](https://gist.github.com/JoshClose/1366260)
Всё хорошо работает, но после выполнения метода ScreenShot.Create(*link*) открывается браузер (по умолчанию) с сайтом *link*

Как убрать?

C# VisualStudio 15.4.2 Framework 4.7

Comment: webBrowser.Navigate( url , false); - не помогло

Answer (score 2):

```
WebBrowser.Dispose() //открывает браузер
```

Поэтому нужно добавить к аргументу функции ScreenShot.Create WebBrowser. Создать его нужно после создания (или перед созданием) формы. А Dispose() по закрытию формы, но нужно заранее очистить Url(это свойство) WebBrowser'a

```
web.Url = null;
web.Dispose();
```

Если же использовать этот код сразу после выполнения ScreenShot.Create, то откроется браузер :(

Comment: Перед тем как добавлять вопрос на стэк нужно хорошо подумать. Потом подумать над проблемой. Подумать над решением проблемы. Подумать, добавлять ли проблему на стэк. Добавить. Решить проблему самому.

Comment: И отметить решение как правильный ответ, если решение работает конечно

Comment: @tym32167 через 2 дня только